# Korganizer entries vanishing

Tags: korganizer

I've been using Korganizer and generally liking it a lot except for a major problem: it sporadically drops large chunks of my entries, apparently into thin air. I'd gone without problems for months but, a few hours ago, opened it to find that, while the calendar events are still in place, my entire to-do list and all journals were gone (again). I was already having trouble keeping it together, so you can imagine how disruptive this is. How can I get my progress back? failing that what do I do to keep this from happening?

I am using: Korganizer 5.15.1 (20.08.1) on Kubuntu 20.10

Thanks!

Comment: I've been keeping rolling backups; today all the to-do items disappeared. This happened right after I clicked Settings > Sidebar > show To Do view. However, upon examining the backups, I found that the journals had actually vanished more than a week ago - they did not appear in the most recent backup, but the one before that. I can stitch things back together, but would really prefer that this didn't happen

Comment: I'm now finding a new mode of disappearance, in which an entry can be found in the ics file for a calendar (grep for keyword, no problem), but does not appear in Korganizer itself (cntr +F keyword, nothing; navigate to date, nothing). I can try to reclaim them by hand by copying the calendar ics to a temporary file, importing it as a new calendar, and then changing the calendar of the imported items but.... if they're not really missing to begin with, will this really fix anything?

Comment: I installed kOrganizer the other day (2023). It lost all the calendar entries I had spent several days organizing. It's a joke calendar app. Don't use it. Whoever heard of a calendar app that loses your appointments?

Comment: I don't understand why it's on the Ubuntu repositories. Seems whoever put it there doesn't care that it cannot retain data.

Comment: Check this out: kOrgaizer lost all 20,000 emails: https://forums.opensuse.org/t/kontact-lost-all-email/139542/4

Comment: Another, on the kde forum (no response to a user reporting data loss): https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=154121

Comment: "Struggling with KOrganizer. Why is it so broken?": https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/mls08a/struggling_with_korganizer_why_is_it_so_broken/

Comment: "korganizer's poor syncronization behaviour causes data [loss]": https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=154121

Comment: Yet Tecmint says its one of the top 7 calendar apps (ha! - joke review of a joke app): https://www.tecmint.com/best-calendar-apps-linux-desktop/

Comment: Well, like I said, I like it a lot when it's not failing catastrophically... this comes to mind xD
https://xkcd.com/937/